# nosuchelementexception error with scanner

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am quite new to java programming, and am having some difficulty with a game that I am attempting to program. Below is the method which is causing the error.

```
public static void dragonNest(Dragon player) {
    int loop = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Territory dragonLand = new Territory(10, 5);
    loop = dragonLand.population + loop;
    int menuChoice;
    int ventureChoice;
    boolean choice = false;
    boolean validOption = true;
    System.out.println("Welcome to your nest, " + player.dragonName);
    while (choice == false) {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to view your hoard");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to venture forth from your nest");
        menuChoice = input.nextInt();
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {

            if (menuChoice > 5 || menuChoice < 1) {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid option");;
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 1){
                System.out.println("Your hoard is worth " + player.dragonHoard + " gold pieces.");
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 2) {
                System.out.println("You fly forth from your den");
                System.out.println("Press 1 to raid a nearby village, 2 to expand your territory, and 3  to return to your nest");
                ventureChoice = input.nextInt();
                do  {
                    if (ventureChoice < 3 || ventureChoice < 1) {
                        System.out.println("That is not a valid option");
                        validOption = false; 
                    }
                    else if (ventureChoice == 1) {
                        System.out.println("You fly forth to raid a nearby village");
                        Random generator = new Random();
                        int dragonPower = player.dragonLevel * 2;
                        int villageOffense = generator.nextInt() + 20 + dragonPower;
                        int villageDefense = generator.nextInt() + 20 + dragonPower;
                        int villageFirepower = generator.nextInt() + 20 + dragonPower;
                        int villageWealth = generator.nextInt() + 20 + dragonPower;
                        Village enemy = new Village(villageOffense, villageDefense, villageFirepower, villageWealth);
                        player = villageCombat(player, enemy);
                    }
                }
                while (validOption == false);
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, this is the text that is displayed:

```
What will be the name of your dragon?
Example
Select your dragon category
Press 1 for a metallic dragon, 2 for a chromatic dragon, and 3 for a primal dragon
1
Are you a brass, copper, bronze, silver or gold dragon?
Press 1 for brass, 2 for copper, 3 for bronze, 4 for silver, and 5 for gold.
1
Welcome to your nest, Example
What would you like to do?
Press 1 to view your hoard
Press 2 to venture forth from your nest
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at DragonNest.dragonNest(DragonNest.java:141)
    at DragonNest.dragonGeneration(DragonNest.java:125)
    at DragonNest.main(DragonNest.java:9)
```

Please tell me if you need more of the program's code to figure this out.

Comment: A good starting point for you here is to enable debug and step through your code to find the fault.

Comment: You are reading a number from the line just fine when you are asking about the color of dragon.  Why not try the same approach?

Comment: I can't find a meaningful difference between the code I used to read the color, and the code I am trying to use in the menu. As for debug mode, it seems to have corroborated what I already believed: that the error occurs when the program runs the line: menuChoice = input.nextInt();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if there is any int first. Replace

```
 menuChoice = input.nextInt();
 if (input.hasNextInt()) {...
```

With

```
 if (input.hasNextInt()) {
       menuChoice = input.nextInt();
       ...
```

I think that your problem arises because you have `input.close();` here and probably in other methods also. If you close Scanner it closes underlying Readable, in this case System.in (you cannot use it after closing). In this project you want to use System.in for some other input so don't close the Scanner